# support for NEON intrinsics using sourcery in Eclipse

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to use intrinsics to utilize the NEON fpu on my cortex A8 processor. I have Eclipse running along with the code sourcery crosscompiler toolchain (win7, 64bit).

when I write this:

```
float32x4_t x;
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'float32x4_t' could not be resolved
```

Can someone please explain me what to do to make this work?

BTW. I can compile and run the my programs not using NEON fine.

Thanks